# How to change the priority of the process using command line

Tags: command-line, permissions, process

I got the following problem when I used this command :

```
renice -19 1744
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not require root permissions to *lower* the priority of any process that you own:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 6965
$ renice 19 6965
6965 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
```

*Raising* the priority does require root permission:

```
$ renice -19 6965
renice: failed to set priority for 6965 (process ID): Permission denied

$ sudo renice -19 6965
6965 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority -19
```

In sum, raising the priority requires root privilege: use `sudo`.

Comment: How to do without being a root user ?

Comment: @vbt If you want to raise the priority and do not have root access, ask your system administrator to give you access to `renice` through `sudo`.

Comment: Got it bro..  @John